# decodedURIComponent in javascript (getCookie function)

Tags: javascript, setcookie, decodeuricomponent

This `getCookie` function code is from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

The part which I cannot understand easily is `decodedCookie`

```
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
```

I've already searched for articles about decodeURIComponent,
and It decodes the `encodedURIComponent`.

But since theres no encoded cookie, why `decodeURIComponent(document.cookie)` needed?

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

This is the code of `setcookie` function from w3schools, and they didn`t set the cookie with`encodeURIComponent`.

So... why?

I need some detailed explanation! Thanks!

Comment: It just looks like horrible code. Not that you wouldn't expect this on w3schools… There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14573223/1048572) other approaches, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38699214/1048572)

Comment: It's a matter of Googling the correct things... running `encodeUriComponent` basically escapes a string so it won't break any of your code. `decodeUriComponent` reverses it.

Comment: @LMulvey Except that there is no `encodeURIComponent` call in the code.

Comment: @Bergi horrible code? can you tell me why you would say that? I`ve searched for getcookie function and many people suggested to use the getcookie function of w3school.

Comment: @Bergi Do I have to use another get/set cookie function?

Comment: @jwkoo The stripping of the blanks and the check whether `c` begins with `name` *are* horrible. The apparently missing `encodeURIComponent` is at least suspicious. w3schools being popular is unfortunate, but says nothing about its quality. I'd recommend to use a function that you feel comfortable with, where you understand what it is doing and why.

Comment: @Bergi fair point. It's awful code.

Comment: @jwkoo If you're just starting out and wanting to learn how to work with cookies, this tutorial may explain things better: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

Comment: @Bergi really appreciate for your advice.

Comment: @Bergi Can I ask one more question?
so If I need some code(like setcookie) to implement in my app, then rather googling the code in w3school, do I have to utilize stackoverflow?

Comment: @LMulvey appreciate it. thanks for your advice

Comment: can I replace the get cookie from w3schools with this function I made or it wrong ?



 function getcookie(cookie) {
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let cookieslist = decodedCookie.split(cookie+"=");
  return cookieslist[1].split(";")[0].trim();
}

Answer (score 1):

It is already mentioned in the tutorial:
Decode the cookie string, to handle cookies with special characters, e.g. '$'

But since we do not have '$' then you can remove it with no effect here.